# Crystal report in vs 2012

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

i made a crystal report in vs 2012.but when i run the project show me the blank page.i tested in IE,Chrome,Firefox.the report don't have any problem.
this is my code:

```
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="1202px" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="1104px" />
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
        <Report FileName="CrystalReport1.rpt">
        </Report>
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy aspnet_client from  C:\inetpub\wwwroot and paste it on your website root.